# Shifting phase in Fourier frequency domain

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

Suppose I have 2 identical Gaussian pulses, but separated by some phase offset. If I take the Fourier transform of it to move from time domain to frequency domain, how can I manipulate the phase terms (imaginary part) such that when I inverse Fourier transform, the two pulses are now aligned?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by Gaussian pulse exactly? Just a function $g(t) = e^{-t^2}$?

Comment: Doesn't even have to be a gaussian pulse. just any 2 signals in time domain that are identical, but offset in phase, say $y_1 = sin(x) , y_2 = sin(x-3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that translation in time (or space, if you prefer) corresponds to a modulation in the frequency domain; i.e.

$$\mathcal{F} (T_\alpha f(x)) = \mathcal{F}( f(x-\alpha)) = E_\alpha \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = e^{-2\pi i \alpha \xi} \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)$$

where I have denoted $T_\alpha$ to be the translation operator, $T_\alpha f(x) = f(x-a)$ and $E_\alpha$ to be the modulation operator, $E_\alpha g(\xi) = e^{-2\pi i \alpha \xi}g(\xi)$ and the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}(f) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-2\pi i \xi x}f(x)dx$.
So if you want the signals to be offset in time, modulate in the frequency domain.

Comment: ok, so use the fourier shift theorem.

Comment: followup questoin. If I can find the phase offset $\triangle \phi$, then I can do $\mathcal{F} (f) * e^{{-i \triangle \phi}}$, then inverse FT to now have the two signals match. QUestion is, how do I find this phase offset?

Comment: If you know for sure that the signals are "identical" then you can just take the ratio on an interval where one of the signals in nonzero.